# Register how to call add_metabox() multiple times from different instances of a class

Tags: php, scope, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin, but I'm not convinced this is a Wordpress-specific issue...

My plugin defines a class. Inside the class's methods, several `add_action()` hooks are used to register callbacks (which are also class methods).

```
MyClass {

    __construct($foo) {

        add_action('hook1', array($this, 'method1') );
        add_action('hook2', array($this, 'method2') );

    }

    public function method1() {...}

    public function method2() {...}

}
```

I instantiate the class in another file...

```
new MyClass('foo');
```

This works just fine. But when I do it twice, only the second works.

```
new MyClass('foo');
new MyClass('bar');
```

In other words, the results of the code above are exactly what I'd expect from the following:

```
// new MyClass('foo');
new MyClass('bar');
```

I've been puzzling over this, and my hunch is that this is related to `$this` and scope issues related to having two callbacks from the same class. But hopefully someone smarter than me can explain it.

**More information**

This issue does appear to be linked to the way Wordpress registers actions. I'm currently on Wordpress v3.8.1 and I'm looking in `/wp-includes/plugin.php`. I see that when I register an action with `add_action()` (line 360) it is basically just a wrapper for `add_filter()` (line 82) which creates a unique `$idx` by calling `_wp_filter_build_unique_id()` (line 774).

**More information2**

I added `var_dump($wp_filter);` after my code and I see BOTH instances listed under the relevant action hook key. So it *looks* like WP knows they are both there...

**Update**

I also tried the following and again, only the final instance had an effect:

```
class Foo1 extends MyClass{}
class Foo2 extends MyClass{}
class Foo3 extends MyClass{}

new Foo1('foo1');
new Foo2('foo2');
new Foo3('foo3');
```

I think this contradicts my theory from above.

**Update2**

This also does not work:

```
MyClass {

    __construct($foo) {


    }

    public function go() {
        add_action('hook1', array($this, 'method1') );
        add_action('hook2', array($this, 'method2') );
    }

    public function method1() {...}

    public function method2() {...}

}

$foo = new MyClass('foo');
$bar = new MyClass('bar');
$foo->go();
$bar->go();
```

**Update3**

As a sanity check, I tried this and it STILL doesn't work. The only difference is that in the following, only the FIRST instance works. Now I'm totally confused.

```
class MyClass1 {

    __construct($foo) {

        add_action('hook1', array($this, 'method1') );
        add_action('hook2', array($this, 'method2') );

    }

    public function method1() {...}

    public function method2() {...}

}

class MyClass2 {

    __construct($foo) {

        add_action('hook1', array($this, 'method1') );
        add_action('hook2', array($this, 'method2') );

    }

    public function method1() {...}

    public function method2() {...}

}

$foo = new MyClass1('foo');
$bar - new MyClass2('bar');
```

**Update4**

I tried @Nihat's suggestion to pass the `$this` by reference...

```
add_action('hook1', array(&$this, 'method1') );
add_action('hook2', array(&$this, 'method2') );
```

...but only the second instance worked (again).

**Here's the COMPLETE original plugin I wrote:**

```
class SDP_Custom_Field {

  public $name = NULL;
  public $slug = NULL;
  public $prefix = NULL;
  public $post_type = 'post'; //The type of Write screen on which to show the meta: 'post', 'page', 'dashboard', 'link', 'attachment' or 'custom_post_type'
  public $meta_box_location = 'normal'; //'normal', 'advanced', or 'side'
  public $meta_box_priority = 'default'; //'high', 'core', 'default' or 'low'
  public $meta_box_field_type = NULL;

  public function __construct( $custom_field_name, $args=array() ) {
    #set the name
    $this->name = $custom_field_name;

    #set the slug
    if (isset($args['slug'])) {
        $this->slug = $args['slug'];
    } else {
        $slug = strtolower($custom_field_name);
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '_', $slug);
        $this->slug = $slug;      
    }

    #set the meta_box_field_type
    if (isset($args['field_type'])) {
        switch ($args['field_type']) {
            case 'text':
                $this->meta_box_field_type = 'text';
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                $this->meta_box_field_type = 'textarea';
                break;            
            default:
                $this->meta_box_field_type = 'text';
                break;
        }

    } else {
        $this->meta_box_field_type = 'text';
    }

    // add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this, '_add_custom_metaboxes'));
    // add_action( 'save_post', array($this, '_save_postdata'));

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array(&$this, '_add_custom_metaboxes'));
    add_action( 'save_post', array(&$this, '_save_postdata'));

    //var_dump( is_object( array($this, '_add_custom_metaboxes') ));

  }

  // public function go() {
  //   add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this, '_add_custom_metaboxes'));
  //   add_action( 'save_post', array($this, '_save_postdata'));
  // }

  #Echo the HTML for this meta box... 
  public function _print_field_HTML( $post ) {

      $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->slug, true );

      // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
      wp_nonce_field( $this->slug.'_custom_box', $this->slug.'_custom_box_nonce' );


      echo '<label for="'.$this->slug.'">'.$this->name.'</label> ';
      echo '<input type="text" id="'.$this->slug.'" name="'.$this->slug.'" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';

      //TODO: Add update button
      //TODO: Add delet button
  }

  public function _add_custom_metaboxes() {
      #http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
      add_meta_box( NULL, $this->name, array(&$this, '_print_field_HTML'), $this->post_type, $this->meta_box_location, $this->meta_box_priority, NULL );
  }




  /**
   * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
   * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
   */
  public function _save_postdata( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because save_post can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[$this->slug.'_custom_box_nonce'] ) )
      return $post_id;

    #http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field
    $nonce = $_POST[$this->slug.'_custom_box_nonce'];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $this->slug.'_custom_box' ) )
        return $post_id;

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;


      if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
          return $post_id;

    /* OK, its safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Sanitize user input.
    $mydata = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$this->slug] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $this->slug, $mydata );
  }

}
```

Comment: why do you need to use this code in construct? you can just do smth like`$worker = new MyClass(); $worker->init('foo');`. I think it should help.

Comment: @DannyChernyavsky The code does not have to be in the constructor. But I already tried with the pattern you suggested and it did not solve the problem. I think the problem has to do with the way Wordpress registers the callback using `$this`.

Comment: in your class, add a new method like add_wp_actions() and setup your actions there. After you instantiate the class like $aa = new Myclass1(..) , call it $aa->add_wp_actions()

Comment: @Nihat I think that is functionally identical to what I posted under **Update2**. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: try putting ampersand before $this to pass by reference    add_action('hook1', array(&$this, 'method1') );
        add_action('hook2', array(&$this, 'method2') );

Comment: @Nihat That's a good idea, but it also did not work. I think the answer you posted earlier was relevant. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Somewhere else I saw that people did indeed made it work with object instances. That is why I deleted it

Comment: @Nihat. You're correct. You *can* make it work with object instances. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action (The documentation) is is contradictory on this point so it's confusing.

Comment: Can you try by commenting out the add_action hook that works? so we can see if other one will work when it is alone. I will open up my work laptop and work on it.. it got me pissed.. what actions are you hooking by the way?

Comment: @Nihat I've tried toggling both on/off and each will work alone. I can rearrange the order of multiple instances and the last will always work.

Comment: I just did on my computer for init method and it worked. I will post below to show it

Comment: I am deleting my answer below because my answer was only showing that you can register callback methods from two instances of same class. But that is not really your problem here. Your problem is why two different action hook callbacks are not adding metaboxes. To fix that, make a simple script and register two action hooks to at least see that you can do two different add_action('add_meta_boxes', ...) (just to make sure wp is playing well) add_meta_boxes are firing. Then check your add_meta_box function.

Comment: @Nihat AHA! It looks like you're on to something. I manually registered two `add_meta_boxes` and only the second one works: 

`function _print_field_HTML() {
    echo "Hello";
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( NULL, 'FOO', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( NULL, 'BAR', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );`

Drop this into a plugin or theme functions.php file and you should see only one new meta box called "BAR".

Comment: good.. change the title of the post to reflect the problem.. it is misleading at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's going on: the first parameter of `add_meta_box()` takes an ID parameter which isn't really explained in [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). Turns out, this needs to be unique or else subsequent `add_meta_box()`s will simply overwrite the previous. This issue had nothing to do with my plugin or object hashes, etc.

This is equivalent to what I was doing wrong (note the first `NULL` param):

```
function _print_field_HTML() {
    echo "Hello";
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( NULL, 'FOO', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( NULL, 'BAR', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );
```

This is works:

```
function _print_field_HTML() {
    echo "Hello";
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( 'A', 'FOO', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( 'B', 'BAR', '_print_field_HTML', 'post' ); } );
```